# Upload archive into a maven repository fail

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I've written the following build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

project.group = 'API'

repositories{
    maven{
        url 'C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/bundaven'
    }
}

dependencies{
    compile 'API:API:1.0'
}


uploadArchives{
    repositories{
        mavenDeployer{
            repository(url: "C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/bundaven")
        }
    }
}
```

But when I was runnig that the following error was thrown:

> > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
> >     Error deploying artifact 'API:upload_archive:jar': Error deploying artifact : Unsupported Protocol: 'C': Cannot find wagon
> >     which supports the requested prot ocol: C

Couln you possibly help me to fix that error?

Comment: Try with `url: "file:///..."`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I've tried this. The same error was occured. What's wrong?

Comment: Paste the exact code you tried, and the exact error message. Hard to believe that it would be exactly the same. Also try with backslashes as path separators (which you'll have to escape).